# Java dynamic binding failed

Tags: java, class, methods, dynamic, this

I don't really understand why the following code doesn't work. I expect `B.f` to be printed out.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.g();
    }
}

class A {
    void g() {
        f();    /* or this.f() */
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void f() {
        System.out.println("B.f");
    }
}
```

The compiler complains:

```
Main.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
        f();    /* or this.f() */
        ^
  symbol:   method f()
  location: class A
1 error
```

From my understanding, the dynamic type of the `this` in `A.g` is always of `B`. As a result, Java's dynamic method lookup should be able to find `B.f` for `this.f` and then execute it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java's dynamic dispatch can only see methods defined on the current class or its superclasses.  Since A does not define the method it cannot see that B defines it and you get an error.

However if the method is any access other than private, B can override it and hence calls to the method on an instance of B will be dynamically dispatched to B's implementation even when accessing the method through an "A" instance type.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work as class A doesn't have any idea about method f(). If you do not want to define `f()` in A, you could make `f()` abstract instead for which You can make class `A` also abstract :

```
abstract class A {
    void g() {
        f();    /* or this.f() */
    }

    abstract void f();
}

class B extends A {
    void f() {
        System.out.println("B.f");
    }
}
```